# How to stop a function from repeating when changing the display to hide

Tags: javascript, event-handling, addeventlistener

This is my `startQuiz()` function which is bounded to the start button.

I click the start button to set the display of my quiz to flex. The issue here is with the submit button.

When I click the submit button and run submit(), everything works out and 1 is logged into the console.

The issue arises when I run `closeQuiz()` which simply changes the quiz display back to none. After running `startQuiz()` to reset the display to flex, running the submit() causes the console to log twice.

This pattern continues in where each time I run `closeQuiz()` and reopen the quiz, submit() ends up running more and more times.

Please help me to run submit() only once and thank you.

```
function startQuiz(){
    quizBox.classList.remove("hide");
    populateAnswers();
}

function closeQuiz(){
    quizBox.classList.add("hide");
}

function populateAnswers(){
    document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click" , () => {
        submit();}
        )
}

function submit(){
    console.log(1)
    }
```

Comment: please check whether any duplicate div id's are present. If it is present, please try to change it. I just assume that might be the issue.

Comment: All the div ids are different. This program just seems to go through more and more recursion each time I call closeQuiz() and startQuiz() for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because in your code whenever `populateAnswers` is being called a new Event listener for `click` is being added to the element with id `submit` since the listener is being added as an anonymous function. Because anonymous functions are not identical even if defined using the SAME unchanging source-code simply called repeatedly, even if in a loop. So every time one more function is being added as a new listener.

In order to resolve the issue send `submit` method reference itself as a listener, which will not add multiple listeners even though the function gets called multiple times. Because If multiple identical EventListeners are registered on the same EventTarget with the same parameters, the duplicate instances are discarded. They do not cause the `EventListener` to be called twice, and they do not need to be removed manually with the removeEventListener() method.

By changing the code with the below implementation will resolve the issue that you are facing.

```js
function populateAnswers(){
    document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click" , submit)
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you run startQuiz(), an event listener is being added to submit button. First time when startQuiz() is invoked, you add an event listener. After closeQuiz() when you call startQuiz() to reset display to flex, an event listener is added to submit button for second time which causes the console to be logged twice with 1 and so on.

Add event listener to submit button only once initially or remove event listener when you call closeQuiz().